# Can't List context routes - incompatible types: List<ProcessorDefinition<?>> cannot be converted to List<ProcessorDefinition>

Tags: routes, apache-camel

I'm trying to simply retrive all the routes in a camel context.
I try to find the documentation but cannot, I used to be able to find it - not anymore.. like the data sheets for the class and methods, for exchange, etc... anyhoot, thank you

I found an stacktrace entry that suggests using something like below

```
package com.ge.digital.fleet.inboundfile.processors;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.ServiceStatus;
import org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition;
import org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class EndpointControlBusProcessor implements Processor {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EndpointControlBusProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        List<ProcessorDefinition> outputProcessorDefs = exchange.getContext().getRouteDefinition("[routeId]").getOutputs();

        for ( ProcessorDefinition rte : outputProcessorDefs ) {

            log.info("ROUTES: " + rte);

        }

But I get this on compile

incompatible types: List<ProcessorDefinition<?>> cannot be converted to List<ProcessorDefinition>

thank you for your help.
```

Comment: to get past compiler error use <ProcessorDefinition<?>> for an unbound type. List<ProcessorDefinition<?>> outputProcessorDefs = exchange.getContext().getRouteDefinition("[routeId]").getOutputs();

Answer (score 0):

to get past compiler error use > for an unbound type. `List<ProcessorDefinition<?>> outputProcessorDefs = exchange.getContext().getRouteDefinition("[routeId]").getOutputs();`